# MVC: How to call Javascript function in action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my view I has a function called `testalert`,and in my controller I has a action called `Index`，I use [javascriptmodel](http://jsm.codeplex.com) can solve my problem,but I find that if my action do not return a view(),for example:just return Json(model)，the javascriptmodel will not work.How to call js function when I return json?Why do the javascriptmodel only be designed to  work well
in return view?

```
function testalert(para) {
     alert(para);
    }

public ActionResult Index()
    {
  //work well  and alert "abc"   
 this.AddJavaScriptFunction("testalert", PageLoadEvent.Ready, null, "abc");
        return View();
    }
public ActionResult GetData()
    {
  var restult="data"; 
 // not work     
 this.AddJavaScriptFunction("testalert", PageLoadEvent.Ready, null, "abc");
   return Json(restult);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done f.e AsyncHelper.Call(url, params) which return as a result promise, and on clientside wait for promise.done and to my stuff.

shorter version:

```
var AsyncAction = (function () {
return {
    //options: passed to $.ajax       
    Call: function (options, helperOptions) {
        return $.ajax(options)
        .done(function (result) {
            helperOptions.onSucceed(result.model);
        });
    }
};
```

})();

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't adapt to the situation.My situation is somebody call the action which may not from the view or may from another program,and once the action be called,the js function will be called.

Comment: I do not exactly know what do you mean @Lyly by 'another program' but if you call some action which return json data which should be processed or whatever this is best solution cause you are returning json, not view - and in this case adding sth by this.AddJavascript will not affect view (will not be reloaded)